# TypeScript - Module '"*.svg"' has no exported member 'ReactComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I'm trying to import an `.svg` file as a React component with TypeScript.

According to the React docs, this is done like so:

`import { ReactComponent as Icon } from './Icon.svg';`

Following the TypeScript docs, I've added this:

```
// custom.d.ts

declare module '*.svg' {
    const content: any;
    export default content;
}
```

and

```
// tsconfig.json

{
    ...
    "files": [
        "custom.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

The SVG is rendering. But I'm getting a TypeScript error:

`[ts] Module '"*.svg"' has no exported member 'ReactComponent'. [2305]`

Here is my full `tsconfig` file if that helps:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-styled-plugin"
      }
    ],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2017"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "files": [
    "custom.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a link to react docs that say this should work (I don't think it did). Thanks 

Comment: @basarat Here you go! https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3718

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You have `export default content;` But you are doing a *named* import (not a default import).

## Fix

Change declaration to export the name you are importing:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');
  export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

## Additional

Recommend not using `files` in tsconfig.json. Instead just use `include`

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! It's correct but I posted a solution below from the CRA repo for a more type specific solution. I'll mark this as correct but maybe edit it with the info below for anyone else that runs into this.

Comment: This is the perfect solution!

Comment: Thanks!  Note that `SFC` is deprecated now - recommend changing `React.SFC` to `React.FunctionComponent`

Comment: @DavidCalhoun Thanks. I've updated the answer to use `React.FC` 

Comment: make my day bro! tnx a lot

Answer (score 19):

**2019** In addition to  @basarat's answer: `React.SFC` is depracated now consider using `React.FunctionComponent` like:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    import React = require('react');
    export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
    const src: string;
    export default src;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you already have plugin `vite-plugin-svgr` installed, simply add this following line to your `vite-env.d.ts` file:

```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

Comment: Should I install it as a dev dependency?

Comment: Yes, it should be a dev dependency. See it's Github Repo as well: https://github.com/lucsky/vite-plugin-svgr

Answer (score 9):

You're naming the custom types as `custom.ts.d` and it should call `custom.d.ts` once the ts compiler is configured to process `ts|tsx` extensions.

After that, you should be able to reference it into your `tsconfig.json` include section just like this:

```
"include": ["custom.d.ts"]
```

Answer (score 6):

My friends, if you are using **Vite** and **vite-plugin-svgr**, just follow these steps:

1. Create a declaration file, name: **client.d.ts** (doesn't matter in **types** folder or in the root)
2. Add this line of code to that file:

   ```
   /// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
   ```
3. Restart the app

**OR**

1. Add this line of code to your **tsconfig.js**:

   ```
   types": ["vite-plugin-svgr/client"]
   ```
2. Restart the app

Personally, I would like to use the first solution.

***UPDATE*** ------------------------------------------------

In the new version (**4.x**), you should use SVG like this:

```
import Logo from "./logo.svg?react";
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the update for vite version 4.x, since there the use of ReactComponent in imports is not allowed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Install svgr plugin and add this to tsconfig files: `types": ["vite-plugin-svgr/client"]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Pull request link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4837/files#diff-6a7d1b055faa1fb39cc4a06915dcf19aR31)

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');
   export const ReactComponent: React.SFC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
   const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

Just because it was helpful to me and somewhat related. If you're getting an error with Jest, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481678/jest-enzyme-svg-sprites-unexpected-token)