# Importing image in gatsby config fail

Tags: typescript, gatsby

I have an app with Gatbsy where I would like to load a series of image to assign to the siteMetaData

I made the following `gatsby-config.ts`

```
import projects from "./src/data/projects";

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    projects
  },
  plugins: [
    //...
  ]
```

My `project.ts` is basically

```
import * as Image from "./images";

export default [
    {
        title: Image.myImage
    }
```

and images.ts is just exporting a series of image :

```
import myImagefrom from "./src/images/projects/image.jpg";
export const myImage;
```

But I get an error at compile

> Cannot find module './src/images/projects/image.jpg'.

But If I click (follow the link) I do see my image in visual code...

So I don't get what am I doing wrong, I tried a lot of different path, but can't manage to make this work.

Comment: where is the `from` in images.ts?

Comment: yes sorry is because I cut some code to make it clearer, i forgot it, will add. But that is not the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webpack not able to import images( using express and angular2 in typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148639/webpack-not-able-to-import-images-using-express-and-angular2-in-typescript)

Comment: I tried with require, but I get the same type of error 

```
  Error: Cannot find module 'src/images/projects/image.jpg'
  Require stack:
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I let you know a solution when I find it.

Answer (score 1):

create global.d.ts file in folder src,and add this line

```
    // fix: gatsby typescript error cannot find module img.jpg or its corresponding type declarations
    declare module "*.jpg" {
      export default "" as string;
    }
    declare module "*.png" {
      export default "" as string;
    }
    
  // fix typescript error of not being able to import svgs has react components
    declare module "*.svg" {
      import React = require('react');
      export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
      const src: string;
      export default src;
    }
```

Sources:
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/gatsby+typescript+error+cannot+find+module+img.jpg+or+its+corresponding+type+declarations
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122106/3044126

Comment: Don't forget to add your `global.d.ts` in your `tsconfig.json` in the `include` Array