# How do I import an SVG into a component using Create React App and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, create-react-app

I have a React project written in JS that I am converting to TS. Using JS, this works:

```
import { ReactComponent as IconPerson } from '../../../icons/person.svg';
```

Using TS, I get this error:

> Cannot find module '../../../icons/person.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.

I have added the following to a new **index.d.ts** file:

```
declare module '*.svg';
```

I have also added the index.d.ts file to the `include` array in my **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  include: ["src", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "index.d.ts"]
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import svg files in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717164/unable-to-import-svg-files-in-typescript)

Comment: `const svg = require("../../../icons/person.svg") as string;` Can you try this ?

Comment: are you using webpack ?

Comment: @monim Yes, but it's within the `react-scripts` package, as I'm using Create React App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');
  export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
}
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122106/2262604

It seems strange to me creating a `ReactComponent` variable, but I no longer get any TS errors.